# My image is ruining my text styling, how can i solve this?

Tags: html, css, image, styles, center

I have created a simple text label with a input field and a image behind it:

```
<p><label for="something" style=" padding: 5px; display:inline-block; width: 440px; border:1px solid white;">Something Since<input type="text" id="datepicker" size="7" readonly></label></p>
```

With all the other text labels, that havent got the **id datepicker** (which contains a image and when clicked on the image a daterpicker pop-up) the text is automaticly centered middle in the box. This isnt the case with the image text..

Here a image which makes it a bit clearer:

[image: problem]

Anyone a clue how i can fix it so the text and image is centered as well in the inline box?

Comment: `I` is always capitalized.

Comment: We would have some ideas but we need your html and css at least to fiddle with this our selves. Maybe make a http://jsfiddle.net as well, also why are you using a `paragraph` tag to contain the input/label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center images and text in one line you can apply `vertical-align: middle` to your image like this:

```
<p>
    <label for="something">Something Since</label>
    <input type="text" id="something" />
    <img src="" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2nxsQ/